# Replicate Python's complex-number-to-string conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, compatibility, complex-numbers, string-conversion

```
import operator
>>> operator.truediv(-5.6, complex(-1, 0)) #eg1
(5.6-0j)
>>> operator.truediv(-5.6, complex(0, -1)) #eg2
(-0-5.6j)
>>> operator.truediv(-5.6, complex(0, 1)) #eg3
5.6j
>>> operator.truediv(-5.6, complex(1, 0)) #eg4
(-5.6+0j)
>>> operator.truediv(5.6, complex(0,-1)) #eg 5
(-0+5.6j)
```

Is there any way to know the exact rule of converting a complex number to its string representation as it appears in the Python interactive interpreter? Like some,

1. In eg1 it prints `0j` but in eg3 it does not.
2. sometimes it prints `0` , `-0` like in eg1 and eg4
3. eg2 and eg5.

I know it doesn't make difference, but I want to implement the exactly same functionality as Python. I mean the output should be exactly the same.

Any help would be much appreciated.
And it is not a homework problem, also thanks for reading.

Comment: Do you mean you want a regular and reproducible output format?

Comment: @CongMa sorry I didn't get you, but I want exact same output as python interpreter.

Comment: You're already showing us the output of the Python interpreter but apparent that's not OK for you. So the problem is?

Comment: @CongMa I want to implement this output in some other language, whose output should match to python's output.

Comment: @Siddharth: Did you look at [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3f2e6f15d64d81633b1fc0b308afc0d6e9026b61/Objects/complexobject.c#L352-L406)?

Comment: @MarkDickinson I did look at it, but wasn't able to understand the else part. Could you please give some hint regarding the else part ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python will always display the imaginary part of a complex number, because otherwise you could not distinguish from the output that it is indeed complex. This is similar to including the `.0` on a floating point number even when it is exactly an integer.

The real part is displayed when it is not exactly +0. In the example you give the real part is being displayed because it is negative zero. Note that in floating point negative and positive zero have different representations even though they compare equal:

```
>>> float.fromhex('-0x0.0')
-0.0
>>> float.fromhex('0x0.0')
0.0
>>> float.fromhex('-0x0.0') == 0.0
True
```

This may not help much in emulating Python's output as you probably can't easily predict when Python will get a negative 0 in its result. For example:

```
>>> neg0 = float.fromhex('-0x0.0')
>>> neg0
-0.0
>>> neg0+0j
0j
```

The addition has normalised the real part to +0

```
>>> neg0*1j
(-0+0j)
>>> 0.0*(-1j)
-0j
```

multiplying by a positive imaginary keeps the negative sign on the real part, but multiplying by a negative imaginary doesn't make the real part negative.

But all of this is just implementation detail so can be different with different implementations of Python.

The fact that floating point has two separate representations for positive and negative zero is a detail of the IEEE 754 implementation of floating point. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

The part of the source code which detects whether or not to output the real part includes:

```
 if (v->cval.real == 0. && copysign(1.0, v->cval.real)==1.0) {
    /* Real part is +0: just output the imaginary part and do not
       include parens. */
```

The first part is true for both forms of zero. The second part is true only if the real part is not negative (`copysign(x,y)` gives the value of `x` with the sign of `y`, so `copysign(1.0, negativezero)` would be `-1`.

Comment: Could you please explain eg2 and eg5 ?

Comment: I thought I had done: multiplication and division by a complex number with a negative imaginary part can result in a real part equal to negative zero and Python displays the real part when it is negative zero. The fact that it does this is an implementation detail.

Comment: I looked at [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3f2e6f15d64d81633b1fc0b308afc0d6e9026b61/Objects/complexobject.c#L352-L406), but not able to understand how does it detect negative zero ?

Comment: I added a bit more explanation.

Comment: Thanks. Since the anomaly is in printing +zero or -zero. So every time before printing I should check whether is it +zero or -zero ? Will this work ?

Comment: yes, that should be fine: if the real part is positive zero then just print the imaginary, otherwise print both real and imaginary parts and be sure to include the sign correctly on the either part for negative zero.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to implement another program to exactly replicate the current behaviour of the CPython interpreter, you can study the source code for complex number representation: [`static PyObject * complex_repr (PyComplexObject *v)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9b6c60cbce4ac45e8ccd7934babff465e9769509/Objects/complexobject.c#L352). This function is responsible for the default conversion of complex numbers to string.

Some of the gory details can be found in the function [`PyAPI_FUNC(char *) PyOS_double_to_string (double val, char format_code, int precision, int flags, int *type)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e2f92de6a90ae11a6d8e01bd17fd88b005516835/Python/pystrtod.c#L792).

I don't think the exact interactive output for floating point numbers is part of the official Python language specification, so probably the source is the best guide here.

---

Edit: If you don't feel like reinventing the wheel, it's probably time to look into [embedding Python in another application](https://docs.python.org/3.6/extending/embedding.html).

Comment: Could you please explain eg2 and eg5 ?